# Python How to insert blank lines between print statements when using Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, formatting

new to Python. I am using Jupyter Notebooks.

I'm trying to add a line between print statements. Is there a way to do this without adding a blank print statement? It seems clunky.

I have tried the suggest \n and <br>. However, this is for inline.

These

```
    print("")
```

are what I'm hoping to remove.

Thank you

CODE EXAMPLE

```
   def form ():
    name = input('Please tell us your name:')
    membership = input('What is your membership number:')
    club = input('Tell us where you want to train. Which club do you want to book your session:')
    time = input('Select time ("10 AM", "12 PM", "2 PM")')
    print("Hello " + name + ".  ")
    print ("Thank you for your booking.")
    print("We look forward to see you at your " + time +" session.")
```

I have tried the inline options above and also "  " double space and [ENTER]

```
   def form ():
    name = input('Please tell us your name:')
    membership = input('What is your membership number:')
    club = input('Tell us where you want to train. Which club do you want to book your session:')
    time = input('Select time ("10 AM", "12 PM", "2 PM")')
    print("")
    print("Hello " + name + ".  ")
    print("")
    print ("Thank you for your booking.")
    print("")
    print("We look forward to see you at your " + time +" session.")
```

DESIRED OUTPUT (without the blank print statements)

Hi John.

Thanks for your booking.

We look forward to see you at your 10 session.

Comment: `print('...', end='\n\n')`?

Comment: What is the issue in this? print("Hello " + name + ".  \n")

Comment: Thank you! '\n\n' works. I tried '\n'

Answer (score 0):

You can add the "end" parameter to the "print" statements, specifying how do you want that line to end.
Is the below code what you need?

```
def form ():
  name = input('Please tell us your name:')
  membership = input('What is your membership number:')
  club = input('Tell us where you want to train. Which club do you want to book your session:')
  time = input('Select time ("10 AM", "12 PM", "2 PM")')
  print("Hello " + name + ".  ", end='\n\n')
  print ("Thank you for your booking.", end='\n\n')
  print("We look forward to see you at your " + time +" session.", end='\n\n')
```

The result is:

```
Hello Jhon.

Thank you for your booking.

We look forward to see you at your 10 am session.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just print a single string with `\n` (newline) in it, each time `\n` appears is when a new line starts.

Also use string formatting instead of multiple prints.

Example:

```py
print('Hello {name}.\n\nThank you for your booking.\n\nWe look forward to see you at your {time} session.'.format(name='John', time='10'))
```

```
Hello John.

Thank you for your booking.

We look forward to see you at your 10 session.
```